# How do you find jobs with sponsorship?

Tags: job-hunting

I am a none European citizen, who lives in Estonia. Many HR contact me in Linkedin for vacant positions in Germany. But, later they notify me that, the employer cannot provide a sponsorship.

I am wondering, how may i find the jobs with sponsorship in Europe?

Comment: I suspect the answer is different depending on which European country you are interested in. Any one specific in your mind?

Comment: I am mostly curios about Germany, and Austria

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the answer depends greatly on what your field is. For software developers, web developers, and others in the IT field generally, Stack Overflow Jobs (https://stackoverflow.com/jobs) is an excellent resource. You can filter by country as well as by whether or not the employer is willing to sponsor a visa and/or offer relocation support.

Since you are already on LinkedIn and getting messages about potential jobs on that platform, you might also consider putting something in your LinkedIn bio about being open to new opportunities in your desired countries, along with a note about needing visa sponsorship. "Open to new opportunities in Germany and Austria with visa sponsorship." Something like that.